# Expose properties of a WPF control to the WinForms host

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, elementhost

Ia have seen several similar posts (so if there is one, please guide me to it), but I haven't found any clear answers.

I've got a WPF control hosted inside a Windows Forms form via `ElementHost`. My WPF control (let's just call it `WpfControl` for the sake of an example) contains a variable that I'd like to expose to my Form. What is the general standard practice to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact it's a WPF control inside a WinForms UI doesn't change anything, it's still a .NET object. So you can just expose a public property from the WPF control and access it from your WinForms code...